# querystring value not retrieiving

Tags: c#, asp.net

Contact no remains empty when i take it in querystring, however Request querystring shows it but it is not assigning to left handside, why ?

Sending value in qs:

```
 Response.Redirect("frmComplaints.aspx?Name=" + this.txtName.Text + "& ContactNo=" + this.txtContact.Text);
```

Retrieving from QS:

```
txtComplainant.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"];
            ContactNo.Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["ContactNo"]);
```

this doesn't take value:

```
ContactNo.Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["ContactNo"]);
```

right hand side shows contant number but not left hand side. why ?

Comment: You probably need to step to next line if you are debugging

Comment: Why you need to do the Convert.ToString ? Request.QuerString returns string only

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space before ContactNo :

```
   Response.Redirect("frmComplaints.aspx?Name=" + this.txtName.Text +
   "&ContactNo=" + this.txtContact.Text);
```

Comment: Remember a Request.QueryString returns a "String" datatype, no need for explicit conversions, also a valid URL cannot contain any whitespace (spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Correct, 'Lost'.

'user3518032', remember that URLs should not contain any spaces. this will break the URL and may cause some unexpected results.

'?' - Start of parameter list

'+' - Adds a space to the url

'&' - Place between parameters